# How does <property> tag in Spring Beans set the value for the private member?

Tags: java, spring

I have a "**MyInterface**" Interface as follows:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void showStatus();
    Map<String,String> getMembers();
}
```

My **"MyClass"** class implements this interface and is as follows:

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    private Map<String,String> members;

    public void setMembers(Map<String, String> members) {
       this.members = members;
    }
    public Map<String, String> getMembers() {
       return members;
    }
}
```

In my beans file I have set the property tag as follows:

```
<property name="members">
    <map>
        <entry key="key1" value="value1"></entry>
    </map>
</property>
```

How does Spring set the value of the **members** variable, even though the setter method is not defined in the interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jordanpg said, field injection is now discouraged and not proposed in the spring framework reference. But the answer to your question:

> How does the property tag in Spring Beans set the value for the private member?

Is :

> by using [**reflection**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

This is not stated in the documentation but you can see it by inspecting the source code of the spring framework. Such as in the [inject method of the `InjectedElement` static inner class of `InjectionMetadata`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5f4d1a4628513ab34098fa3f92ba03aa20fc4204/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/InjectionMetadata.java#L171):

```
protected void inject(Object target,
                      @Nullable String requestingBeanName, 
                      @Nullable PropertyValues pvs)
                throws Throwable {

            if (this.isField) {
                Field field = (Field) this.member;
                ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
                field.set(target, getResourceToInject(target, requestingBeanName));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information. But, back then, why did we need setters, when we can directly access and set properties using reflection?

Comment: Because reflection is a kind of meta-operation not intended for normal use. Moreover reflection is [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502674/why-is-reflection-slow).

Answer (score 1):

Field injection:  http://vojtechruzicka.com/field-dependency-injection-considered-harmful/

Still supported by Spring, [but not even documented anymore](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators).  I assume it's on a long-term deprecation roadmap, but in my experience lots of people still use it in spite of the mountains of recommendations not to.